# Is there a beautiful gwt css/theme?

Tags: css, gwt

Is there a beautiful theme to override the predefined gwt theme, i.e., a css file like clean.css, standard.css, but with a more beautiful look & feel? The original ones are rather plain and not so desirable. The generator "http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/" is not quite good either.

Comment: Found [this](http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can use [GWT boostrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out these:

- http://cleangwt.appspot.com/
- http://www.spiffyui.org/
- https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3

Answer (score 2):

There is also HexaCss (www.lteconsulting.fr/hexacss) which allows you to bind your application to multiple css files (thus you can theme it easily) and allows to bind to existing css files (like bootstrap themes for instance).

Check this demo for example, where you can change the bootstrap theme dynamically with the top-right list box : http://www.lteconsulting.fr/hexacss/demo/sample4/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can always use CSS Styling with GWT in most of the elements. So you can use any existing CSS theme and use it with following conditions :

1. Remove the default styling for all widgets with 
       {widget_name}.removeStyleName(gwt-{WidgetName})
2. Then add he css class with : 
           {widget_name}.addStyleName(gwt-{WidgetName})

For certain static things, you can always use setInnerHTML or directly specify CSS classes to use in your HTML files.

I have successfully used Bootstrap ( Not GWTBootstrap) in my project for variety of widgets.Plus the grid system of Bootstrap also works perfectly in GWT.

If you want to use other libraries, you can try Sencha. They have good design themes for GWT

Answer (score -1):

[Putnami Web Toolkit](http://pwt.putnami.org/) (**PWT**) is a GWT framework based on Twitter's Bootstrap 3.2, so your webapp are **responsive** and can be **easily themed**.
Its **attractive graphic components** are easy to expand and to customize.

Documentation and tutorials can be found on official site : http://pwt.putnami.org/ (the site was made using its own framework).